# Problema com animate.css em fontes no Safari

Tags: css

Estou com problemas na renderização de fontes que possuem efeitos do plugin Animate.css
E isso só acontece no Safari. [Link do site](http://www.fortuneimport.com.br/).

Como exemplo, os três primeiros links do menu estão sem nenhum efeito, e os três últimos estão com as classes `"animated fadeInDown"`.
(Ampliem a imagem para ver melhor)
[image: Exemplo de exibição no Safari]

A fonte fica meio "deformada", mas no `hover`, como vocês podem ver no exemplo, ela fica normal.

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
       transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    100% {
       opacity: 1;
       -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
       transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        -ms-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
.fadeInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
}

.nav > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 11px 15px;
    color: #b3b3b3
}
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #cf6150;
}
```

O que pode ser feito para resolver isso?

Comment: Tenta adicionar o código, ou alguns excertos que aches importante, para esclarecer melhor o que se está a passar. Sem código fica difícil de imaginar o que será.

Comment: Cara, eu já tive esse problema em um projecto com webfonts e a solução foi aumentar o tamanho da letra 1 pixel. Tente essa solução, limpe a cache antes de testar.

Comment: Opa, erro meu! Já adicionei partes do código que acho relevantes. E quanto a aumentar 1px o tamanho da fonte, não adiantou não... E isso acontece em outras partes do site também, com vários tipos de tamanho de fonte, e várias fontes diferentes. Inclusive as padrões do sistema (arial, tahoma, etc...)

Comment: O problema não está nesta parte do código, copiei o css e não reproduzi o problema, funcionou perfeitamente. Veja: http://jsfiddle.net/Wqpnq/2/   Verifique se não existe algum css aplicado em cima do ul ou li ou até mesmo na classe nav

Comment: @Filipe Isso acontece com qualquer h1, h2, h3, p.. Enfim, com tudo... E acessando esse seu link, aqui continua com o problema no Safari. A fonte fica com o mesmo problema...

Comment: Testei aqui no Safari e fica bem, na última versão 7.0.3, qual a versão que utilizas?

Comment: Coloca no http://jsfiddle.net e edita sua pergunta com o link de um exemplo

Comment: 5.1.7, é a versão para Windows. Mas o cliente possui MAC e acontece a mesma coisa. Adicionei o link do jsfiddle.net do Filipe na pergunta!

Comment: Estou usando `Mac OSX` e nesse exemplo a fonte está normal. Seria interessante você colocar o seu próprio menu como exemplo.

Comment: Opa Paulo Maciel, blz? Então, aqui nesse exemplo que o Filipe postou está ocorrendo o mesmo problema com a fonte quando eu acesso.

Comment: @PauloMaciel editei a resposta com o link do site. O estranho é que é em todos os computadores da empresa, e no computador do cliente (um macbook pro).

Comment: @Marcus se você puder descreva na sua pergunta qual o efeito que você está tentando fazer, porque estou vendo aqui e o menu realmente está problemático, não está consistente o efeito que você quer nele. Se puder descreva como você quer sua animação.

Comment: @PauloMaciel eu postei o link do site na pergunta. O efeito que está sendo usado é o fadeInDown, somente ao carregar o site. O único problema mesmo é com a fonte no Safari.

Comment: @marcus-david Veja a resposta que deixei para você, eu testei aqui no Safari e resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde.

Adicione `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` no bloco `.nav > li > a`  para que fique como abaixo:

```
.nav > li > a {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 11px 15px;
color: #B3B3B3;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Adicione na declaração dos outros elementos também onde as fontes ficam desconfiguradas, ex: H1, H2, H3..

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito amigo! Isso resolveu o problema! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Percebi que você não consta no seu site a propriedade css **text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;**. Já tentou isso?